# Command UPDATE using existing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update the records of some tables, and I tried using the following command:

```
UPDATE auction a        
JOIN (SELECT bidding_price, user_id, auction_id FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id = a.auctionID ORDER BY bidpack_buy_date DESC LIMIT 1) ult_lance_a
SET a.auc_final_price=ult_lance_a.bidding_price, a.buy_user=ult_lance_a.user_id
WHERE a.auctionID=ult_lance_a.auction_id;
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
#1054 - Column 'a.auctionID' unknown in 'where clause'
```

what did I do wrong?

Here is the return of the command: `SELECT bidding_price, user_id, auction_id FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id = XXX ORDER BY bidpack_buy_date DESC LIMIT 1`

> bidding_price = 6.23
> user_id = 1720
>  auction_id = 1818

In the `auction` table, there are the columns:

> auc_final_price
>  bidding_price
> auctionID

There are several records, but the records are the same for the columns: **auction_id** and **auctionID**.

What I need is to just grab the LAST value entered in the `bid_account` table, and copy the values to the `auction` table.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: are you sure `auction_id` exists in both `auction` and `bid_account`?

Comment: The command speaks what I need. I need to update all the records of the `auction` table by inserting the values values obtained in the JOIN, which are in the `bid_account` table.

Comment: It doesn't really speak to what you need, and it's very hard to back calculate the logic from a query based on the query alone.

Comment: @mankowitz No, the columns have different names for each table. `auctionID and auction_id `

Comment: which table has which one? You are using `auction_id` for both.

Comment: Table auction = auctionID and table bid_account = auction_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a better way to phrase your update, but if you want to use correlated subqueries, then you might need to put them directly into the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE auction a
SET auc_final_price = (SELECT bidding_price
                       FROM bid_account
                       WHERE auction_id = a.auctionID
                       ORDER BY bidpack_buy_date DESC
                       LIMIT 1),
    buy_user = (SELECT user_id
                FROM bid_account
                WHERE auction_id = a.auctionID
                ORDER BY bidpack_buy_date DESC
                LIMIT 1);
```

Actually, I think we can still write your query using update join syntax.  Since your tables are large, you may try joining to a temporary table (in place of a matetialized view):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    auctionView ( INDEX(auction_id) ) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
AS (
    SELECT b1.auction_id, b1.bidding_price, b1.user_id
    FROM bid_account b1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT auction_id, MAX(bidpack_buy_date) AS max_buy_date
        FROM bid_account
        GROUP BY auction_id
    ) b2
        ON b1.auction_id = b2.auction_id AND b1.bidpack_buy_date = b2.max_buy_date
);

UPDATE auction a
INNER JOIN auctionView b
    ON b.auction_id = a.auctionID
SET
    a.auc_final_price = b.bidding_price,
    a.buy_user = b.user_id;
```

Comment: Are you certain that the `auction` table has an `auctionID` column?

Comment: Yes, there is. :/

Comment: @Wendler I see the problem now.  That error is coming from the `WHERE` clause in your correlated subquery.  I don't think your current syntax can work; see my answer for a possible alternative.

Comment: Here the command did not work, sorry for the lack of information, I updated the question in more detail than I need, can you check it please?

Comment: `did not work` ... this does not let me update my answer.  _What_ did not work?  I gave you 2 queries, did they both fail?

Comment: Try the second query, don't use the first one for now.

Comment: In your second command, will it query all the records in the bid_account table for a given auction_id? Because it seems so, and that makes it very slow, because there are millions of records in this table, so I put that date condition, that it directly searches only the last record entered for that ID.

Comment: I forgot to mention the error I get for the second query: #1205 - Lockout timeout exceeded. Try restarting the transaction

Comment: @Wendler Try doing an update join to a temporary table, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: There is a syntax error, I could not find out what it is. It's in the last parentheses, and early in UPDATE.

Comment: 2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 424)
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "UPDATE" at position 429)

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon somewhere?  For simple syntax issues, SO is not the best tool to be using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174136/discussion-between-wendler-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Great, can you help me with a last chat question?

Comment: Just ask the question please.

Comment: Is that the same question, I just wanted to know how I can unify three updates to do in the same query, why I need to update in three tables.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you are missing the "ON" clause in your join and trying to accomplish the same thing using the "WHERE" clause of your subquery.

a.auctionID doesn't exist within the context of the subquery `SELECT bidding_price, user_id, auction_id FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id = a.auctionID ...`, so it's throwing an error.

Try it like this, instead:

```
UPDATE 
    auction AS a
INNER JOIN 
    /* Find the highest (max) bidpack_buy_date for each auction */
    (SELECT MAX(bidpack_buy_date) AS `Max Date`, auction_id FROM bid_account GROUP BY auction_id) AS maxdates
    ON 
    maxdates.auction_id = a.auctionID
INNER JOIN
    /* The data from bid_acount that accompanies the max dates found above */
    bid_account AS ult_lance_a
    ON
    ult_lance_a.bidpack_buy_date = maxdates.`Max Date`
    AND
    ult_lance_a.auction_id = maxdates.auction_ID
SET 
    a.auc_final_price = ult_lance_a.bidding_price,
    a.buy_user = ult_lance_a.user_id
```

Code I used to set up test:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bid_account;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bid_account (
    auction_id int,
    user_id int, 
    bidding_price numeric(8,2),
    bidpack_buy_date DATETIME
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS auction;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auction (
    auctionID int,
    buy_user int,
    auc_final_price numeric(8,2)
);

INSERT INTO 
    bid_account 
        (auction_id, user_id, bidding_price, bidpack_buy_date)
    VALUES
        (1,1, 10.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:01 PM'),
        (1,2, 20.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:02 PM'),
        (1,3, 30.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:03 PM'),
        (1,4, 40.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:04 PM'),
        (2,1, 10.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:01 PM'),
        (2,2, 20.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:02 PM'),
        (2,3, 30.00, '2017-01-01 12:00:03 PM');

INSERT INTO 
    auction 
        (auctionID)
    VALUES
        (1),
        (2),
        (3),
        (4),
        (5),
        (6),
        (7);
```

Comment: Can you explain what it would be: `sub.auction_id`?

Comment: Sorry, `sub.auction_id` should be `ult_lance_a.auction_id`. (I copied from the wrong attempt). My answer is fixed now.

Comment: There is still a problem with the logic in your update.  Look closely at the original correlated subquery and you will see it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you referring to the ORDER BY that references a column that's not in the SELECT?

Comment: No, the `WHERE` clause in the correlated subquery which you have removed in your answer.  It changes the logic.

Comment: I wasn't clear on the intended logic to begin with, but the focus of the OP's question seemed to be the origin of the error, which I believe I have pointed out. I'm happy to revise, if OP would provide some sample data and feedback as to the specific need.

Comment: Here the command did not work, sorry for the lack of information, I updated the question in more detail than I need, can you check it please?

Comment: Yes, I will, but it'll be a few minutes before I can start on it.

Comment: Okay, @Wendler check my revised answer. Assuming I'm understand your needs correctly, it should meet those needs. It worked properly using the test code I posted. Let me know if you're still having problems.